# Ocaml equivalent for Lisp's let*?

Tags: lisp, ocaml, let

I'd rather use `let ... and ... and ... in` than nested `let`'s when possible, but the normal let syntax doesn't allow this for expressions that depend on each other.

Not allowed:

```
let encrypt password =
    let seed = int 16
    and keys = xlat seed (length password)
    and plaintext = map code (explode password) in
        map2 logxor plaintext keys
```

Does OCaml have an equivalent to Lisp's `let*`, which does allow this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On ocaml indenting style for this kind of nested let-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670111/on-ocaml-indenting-style-for-this-kind-of-nested-let-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `let`'s don't need nested indentation, so that's good enough.

Comment: In fact, `let*` is usually implemented as a macro that expands to nested `let`s.

Comment: Ha. Gotta give it up for macros.